# Connect to SAP Hana XS using http connection from JAVA

Tags: hana, httpconnection, hana-xs

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to Hana XS using http connection from java, I've spent days searching for anything relevant on internet but couldn't find anything.

I was just trying a few thing and the best i could come up with is :

```
public static boolean testConnection(String host, String port,String userID,String certificate)
{
    boolean success = false;
    String https_url = "https://"+host+":"+port;
    URL url ;
    try{
        url = new URL (https_url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", certificate);
        int response = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response:  "+ response);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return success;
}
```

This Obviously is not working as i don't know how to form the connection string and send the request. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Leveraging an ODATA service implemented in SAP HANA XS or do you want to parse the actual HTML that is generated when you connect to a XS backed webpage?

Comment: Hi! i just want to connect to Hana XS and see if the connection is successful or not! I'm implementing a TestConnection feature for HANA HTTPS connection.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a HCP HANA xs page or to a HANA instance in your local network?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a HANA XS(residing somewhere else) from a remote machine!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounded like you are just wanting to see if your XS engine is running, the easiest way to accomplish that is doing something like this:

```
function doPing(lv_server){
    $.ajax({url: "http://"+lv_server+":8090/",
           type: "HEAD",
           timeout:1000,
           statusCode: {
               200: function (response) {
                   $(imgname).attr('src', 'images/online.png');
               },
               404: function (response) {
                   $(imgname).attr('src', 'images/offline.png');
               },
               400: function (response) {
                   $(imgname).attr('src', 'images/offline.png');
                  },
               0: function (response) {
                   $(imgname).attr('src', 'images/offline.png');
               }              
           }
    });
}
```

This assumes a standard SAP HANA install where the default port for the XS engine is **80XX** where **XX** is the instance number in this example instance number **90**.

Then you are setting an image to indicate offline or online based on the response from the call.

This works for any SAP HANA system running the XS classic ([xsc](/questions/tagged/xsc)) engine as there is a default "landing page" to indicate the XS engine is up and running.